# How to rotate in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm using the GuiViewer3D to view 3d files on my angular app. It loads properly but I can only rotate from the cube view on the top right. Dragging anywhere else on the screen doesn't do anything (like in the online viewer). I tried writing an extension and putting this in the load method but still does nothing. I'm not sure if this is meant to be a feature and if not, if I'm implementing the rotation correctly :

```
    let nav = this.viewer.navigation;
    let up = nav.getCameraUpVector();
    let axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
    let speed = 10.0 * Math.PI / 180;
    let matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(axis, speed * 0.1);

    let pos = nav.getPosition();
    pos.applyMatrix4(matrix);
    up.applyMatrix4(matrix);
    nav.setView(pos, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    nav.setCameraUpVector(up);
```

Also, I've seen on the online viewer there's a toolbar (at the bottom of the pic) which allows you to do different things. Does autodesk provide these buttons/functionalities (ie a basic toolbar) or are we meant to make our custom functions? I couldn't find any documentation regarding it.

[image]

EDIT : Here is my code in the .ts file for the viewer (without setting up extension) :

```
 let  viewerOptions = {
      env: 'AutodeskProduction',
      api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
      getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
          var token = 'TOKEN';
          var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
          onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
      }
    };
      Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(viewerOptions, () => {
        let config3d = {
          extensions: ['MyExtension'],
        }
        let viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(this.container.nativeElement, config3d);
        viewer.start();
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(this.urn, function (doc) {
          let viewables = doc.getRoot().search({ 'type': 'geometry' });
          viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables[1]);
          
        }, this.onDocumentLoadFailure);
        
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

The Viewer should have the rotation and toolbar by default ([following this tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/)). From your description, it seems like you have a basic Three.js viewer.

Comment: I followed that tutorial, but I don't have the toolbar or rotation (outside of viewcube). updated the question with how I'm initializing viewer